# SetCompoundDrawableTintList for Android < 5

Tags: android

I am trying to change the color of of an EditText to something at runtime (the color is also calculated at runtime).

[SetCompoundDrawableTintList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawableTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)) seems to do the trick. But it is only available starting from API Level 23.

Can I somehow archive the same effect for API Level < 23? Note that I want to set the color at runtime and do not know them in advance.